# Programmatically retrieve the tabsize of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am writing a plugin which needs to retrieve the tab size setting of eclipse.

That is the 'Windows > Preferences > General > Editor > Text Editors > Displayed tab width' setting

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?
Thank for your help.

Comment: What tab size would that be?

Comment: Windows->Preference->editor->text editors->Displayed tab width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is in a text editor extending `TextEditor` you can get the tab setting from the source viewer configuration using:

```java
getSourceViewerConfiguration().getTabWidth(getSourceViewer());
```

elsewhere you could use:

```java
IPreferenceStore store = EditorsUI.getPreferenceStore();

store.getInt(AbstractDecoratedTextEditorPreferenceConstants.EDITOR_TAB_WIDTH));
```